# Laravel : Query Builder return extra row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I was trying to generate a report with with service, customer & transaction

```
$status_report = \DB::table('services')
                 ->join('customers','services.id','customers.service_id')
                 ->join('transactions','customers.id','transactions.customer_id')    
                 ->select('customers.customer_name','customers.uniqueId','customers.id',
                          'customers.mobile_number', \DB::raw('transactions.id as t_id'),'customers.box_number' ,'customers.voucher_number' ,'services.name','customers.status','transactions.net_amount','transactions.paid_amount','customers.receive_date','customers.receive_time','customers.referrar','transactions.due')
                 ->groupBy('customers.customer_name','customers.voucher_number','services.name','customers.status','customers.uniqueId','customers.id','transactions.paid_amount','transactions.due','customers.box_number')
                 ->orderBy('customers.status')    
                 ->get();
```

The above Query will return single row data for every transaction. But the problem is when i made `customers.status == 1` it returns same row double. How could i get the distinct transaction row for every transaction?

Comment: It should be unique per grouping criteria *'customers.customer_name','customers.voucher_number',
    'services.name','customers.status','customers.uniqueId',
    'customers.id','transactions.paid_amount','transactions.due',
    'customers.box_number'*

Comment: When you join tables A, B and C then you have all possible cross product triples filtered out by the join conditions, that means triples `(a1,b1,c1)` and `(a1,b1,c2)` are a possibility. Note how the pair `(a1,b1)` is repeated but the actual row is distinct. Your problem is that you don't see it's distinct because you only show columns from the 2 tables. In this case joining the 2 tables and adding a `whereExists(/* subquery to filter based on the 3rd table */)` is better